# Why is my websocket listener only firing one time when declared in useEffect with empty array as the second argument?

Tags: reactjs, websocket, socket.io, use-effect, use-state

I'm building my first websocket application with React, Socket.io, and Express. I've been trying to use this as an opportunity to learn the Hooks API as well, and it's proving to be a little tricky.

I establish a listener on the socket in the client app inside a useEffect that only runs after the first render (I'm passing it an empty array as a second argument). The listener works when a user logs in from this client application, but when opening up a second window and logging in from a different connection, it does not register again for that application. The second window has the correct array of users from the server.

I'm looking for an explanation about *why* my app is behaving this way. I've read a [recommendation](https://adamrackis.dev/state-and-use-reducer/) that I should be using useReducer instead of useState in this case, but I'm not sure how that would make a difference because the `console.log` in my callback for the event listener on the socket is still not registering anything. Even in the example, the author is still explaining that the state should be changed and a re-render triggered. And although I've used an empty array as a second argument in the useEffect, it shouldn't matter because the event listener is established there.

I've avoided situations where I write multiple useEffects that open and close connections or re-write multiple event listeners over again.

I establish my connection at the top of the page:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react"
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";

import Layout from "../components/layout"
import Login from "../components/login"

//establish socket connection
const socket = socketIOClient("http://localhost:4001")
```

I use useState to create state here:

```js
  ///one is for the current user, the second is for the other users with already established connections
  const [user, setUser] = useState("loading")
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([])
```

And then I use my first useEffect hook to check for a logged-in user in localStorage as well as add an event listener on the socket:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
      checkForLoggedInUser()
      socket.on("backendUsers", (data) => {
        setUsers(data)
        console.log(data)
      })
    return () => socket.disconnect()
    }, [])
```

As mentioned above, the listener works perfectly the first time, when the user logs in using the form or is found in localStorage. It registers with the server, and the server emits "backendUsers", notifying that an update just occurred. But when I add another user in a different (incognito) window, the listener is not caught again although "backendUsers" is emitted when the second user logs in. The second window has the up-to-date list of users, but in the first window I expect an updated array of users logged in the console as well as a re-render, showing that state has updated and the users are correctly listed out in the DOM.

Here's the entirety of my frontend code:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef }from "react"
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";

import Layout from "../components/layout"
import Login from "../components/login"

const socket = socketIOClient("http://localhost:4001")

const IndexPage = () => {

  const [user, setUser] = useState("loading")
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
      checkForLoggedInUser()
      socket.on("backendUsers", (data) => {
        setUsers(data)
        console.log(data)
      })
      return () => socket.disconnect()
    }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if(user !== null && user !== "loading"){
      window.addEventListener('beforeunload', logoutUserFromServer)
    }
  }, [user])
  //variables in useEffect are scoped to the moment they are executed. This is what makes useEffect work
  //if you want access to variables that change, use useReducer

  const logoutUserFromServer = () => {
    socket.emit("logout", user)
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', logoutUserFromServer)
  }

  const checkForLoggedInUser = () => {
    const user = localStorage.getItem('websocketUser')
    if (user){
      loginUser(user)
    } else {
      setUser(null)
    }
  }

  const loginUser = (user) => {
    localStorage.setItem('websocketUser', user)
    setUser(user)
    socket.emit("login", user)
  }

  return (
    <Layout>
      <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
        {user == "loading" ? user : <Login user={user} loginUser={loginUser}/>}
        <br/>
        {users.length ? `The users are: ${users.join(", ")}` : "No users"}
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default IndexPage
```

And here's the server side code (I'm using Express.js here). The main listener to watch is `login`:

```js
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const socketIo = require("socket.io");

const port = process.env.PORT || 4001;
const index = require("./routes/index");

const app = express();
app.use(index);

const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = socketIo(server);

let users = []

io.on("connection", socket => {
  console.log("New client connected")

  //emits "backendUsers" with the current users array anytime a user logs in from any client connection
  socket.on("login", user => {
    users.push(user)
    socket.emit("backendUsers", users)
    console.log(users)
  })

  socket.on("logout", user => {
    users = users.filter(name => name!== user)
    console.log(`${user} logged out`, users)
  })

  socket.on("disconnect", () => console.log("Client disconnected"));
});

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));

};
```

Comment: Please add a javascript tag to the question, in order for it to be formatted correctly(colors). Also, there is a lot of code. Can you try narrowing it down to the actual problem?

Comment: There are javascript tags already, the color is formatted correctly on my computer. The code at the end is just for reference. At the top I put in the specific code.

Answer (score 1):

useEffect with and `[]` as second argument is equvilant to `componentDidMount()` in class-based components; so this code

```js
useEffect(() => {
  checkForLoggedInUser()
  socket.on("backendUsers", (data) => {
    setUsers(data)
      console.log(data)
    })
  return () => socket.disconnect()
}, [])
```

Is roughly the same as this one

```
componentDidMount() {
 checkForLoggedInUser()
 socket.on("backendUsers", (data) => {
   setUsers(data)
   console.log(data)
 })
}

componentWillUnmount(){
  socket.disconnect()
}
```

so this code will only run once, when the component is mounted; if it is not what you want you should add some dependencies to that second array argument to run when dependencies change, or remove it completely  to run after every render. check the [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) documentation for further reading

Comment: Hey thanks. I understand that already. The event listener for the socket is created in that function though. I shouldn't have to put an event listener on a socket more than once, right?

Comment: @critsmet yeah you don't define an event listener multiple time, and that is an ok place to define that eventlistner

Comment: In [this](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/socket-react/) example, the coder puts the event listener in the componentDidMount, and the socket still registers all future socket emissions from that listener.

Comment: are you saying that I should use a useEffect that calls socket.on() on every rerender?

Comment: @critsmet no, how did u deduced that?

Comment: because you said that was a fine place to define it, but didn't offer another solution

Answer (score 1):

I needed to be using the io variable in the backend instead of the socket variable! socket.emit only sends to the receiving client. io.emit sends to all connections.